# how to deal with async calls in Ajax 4.0(using jquery?)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

in my code i have done something like this.

```
 $.get('/Home/Module/Submit',
                { moduleName: ModName,
                    moduleParameters: moduleParameters
                },

   function(result) {


       $("#" + target).html(result);

   });
```

when i put alert in the function(result) {..}
it shows html perfectly(both in alert and at the 'target'-on the .aspx page)
BUT when i remove the alert.. on the page the 'html' don't appear or appear randomly (this method is called multiple times)

i think that the 'result' comes to function asynchronously thats why it is not bind with the respective 'div'
however in the last iteration it gets bind every time.

can we make process stop  until data gets bind?
or is there any functionality (like alert) which can make data bind..
without disturbing UI (unlike alert)?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function makes use of `target` which is defined in an outside scope, possibly global. You say you're doing this call several times, and that the last iteration works every time, so I'm guessing that `target` is actually changed by some outside influence? In that case, it may very well be that the value of `target` is not what you think it is, at the time of execution. You can create a new closure in which `target` will be sure not to change:

```
$.get('/Home/Module/Submit', { data }, (function(t) {
    return function(result) {
        $("#" + t).html(result);
    }
})(target));
```

What we're doing here is to create a new anonymous function that *returns* the callback function you want to use. You can think of it as a factory function. This function is being called immediately, just *before* the call to `get`, as it has to be evaluated to work out the third parameter to pass to `get`. We call this function, passing `target`, so the value of `target` will be the value it has by the time of the AJAX call, not, like before, by the time of the AJAX response. A new closure will be created for each iteration, where its respective `t` parameter will correspond to the value of `target` at the time of its creation.

You do *not* want to come up with something that will keep the JavaScript from executing until a certain other piece of code has been executed.

Comment: the html gets bind randomly ...but with last position is always gets displayed...this issue comes only in Internet Explorer, not in Chrome and Firefox